# How to display name in hashing and how to linked list?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

I made 11 size in hash table and this include the user input such as 1: add, 2: remove, 3: search and 4: display function. 
I only have a problem with display function and linked list..

When I add person which called "ben" and then I press number 4 which is display table and it only displays the value, not a string or char.

For example, I add the person name which ben into the hash table, and then I display a hash table, this is the result I get.

```
------------------------------
 Hashing Table
------------------------------
 Index    Value
 0        -2147483648
 1        309
 2        -2147483648
 3        -2147483648
 4        -2147483648
 5        -2147483648
 6        -2147483648
 7        -2147483648
 8        -2147483648
 9        -2147483648
 10       -2147483648
----------------------------
-----------------------------
 Your hash table size is: 11
-----------------------------
 Enter the number below:
 1: Add element
 2: Remove element
 3: Search element
 4: Display all element
 0: Exit

 Your selection:
```

As you can see debug above, Index 1 hold 309 value (ben) but this is not what I want.
I want something like this below.

```
------------------------------
 Hashing Table
------------------------------
 Index    Value
 0        -2147483648
 1        ben
 2        -2147483648
 3        -2147483648
 4        -2147483648
 5        -2147483648
 6        -2147483648
 7        -2147483648
 8        -2147483648
 9        -2147483648
 10       -2147483648
----------------------------
-----------------------------
 Your hash table size is: 11
-----------------------------
 Enter the number below:
 1: Add element
 2: Remove element
 3: Search element
 4: Display all element
 0: Exit

 Your selection:
```

Also, I am very confused on how to create the linked list. I have to add linked list.

Here is an example of what I really want,

```
------------------------------
 Hashing Table
------------------------------
 Index    Value
 0        -2147483648
 1        ben, leon
 2        -2147483648
 3        -2147483648
 4        -2147483648
 5        -2147483648
 6        jame
 7        -2147483648
 8        -2147483648
 9        -2147483648
 10       -2147483648
----------------------------
-----------------------------
 Your hash table size is: 11
-----------------------------
 Enter the number below:
 1: Add element
 2: Remove element
 3: Search element
 4: Display all element
 0: Exit

 Your selection:
```

As you can see an example debug above, I add ben which goes into index 1. 
Also, if I add leon, this should go into index 1 but there is no space so I 
have to create a linked list in order to add leon in index 1.

Here is my code, I really appreciate if anyone helps.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<limits.h>
#include "string"

using namespace std;

void DisplayHashTable(int Array1[], int Size1)
{
    system("cls"); /* <-- See Line 192 to 197 for detail.*/
    int i;
    cout << "------------------------------\n";
    cout << " Hashing Table\n";
    cout << "------------------------------\n";
    cout << " Index \t  Value\n";

    for (i = 0; i<Size1; i++)
        cout << " " << i << "\t  " << Array1[i] << "\n";
    cout << "----------------------------\n";
}

void LookUpHashTable(int Array2[], int HashFunction2, int Size2)
{
    system("cls");
    int Position2, a, ASCIIsum2 = 0, n = 0;
    string Element2;

    cout << " Enter element or name you want to search: ";
    cin >> Element2;

    for (a = 0; a != Element2.length(); ++a)
    {
        ASCIIsum2 += int(Element2[a]);
    }

    Position2 = ASCIIsum2 % HashFunction2;

    while (n++ != Size2)
    {
        if (Array2[Position2] == ASCIIsum2) {
            cout << "\n###################################\n";
            cout << " NOTE: " << Element2 << " value number is " << ASCIIsum2 << ".\n Element or name found at index " << Position2 << "\n";
            cout << "###################################\n\n";
            break;
        }
        else
            if (Array2[Position2] == INT_MAX || Array2[Position2] != INT_MIN)
                Position2 = (Position2 + 1) % HashFunction2;
    }

    if (--n == Size2)
    {
        cout << "\n################################################\n";
        cout << " NOTE: Element or name not found in hash table\n";
        cout << "################################################\n\n";
    }
}


void AddElementHashTable(int Array3[], int HashFunction3, int Size3)
{
    system("cls");
    int  Position3, a, ASCIIsum3 = 0, n = 0;
    string Element3;

    cout << " Enter new element or name: ";
    cin >> Element3;

    for (a = 0; a != Element3.length(); ++a)
    {
        ASCIIsum3 += int(Element3[a]);
    }

    Position3 = ASCIIsum3 % HashFunction3;

    while (Array3[Position3] != INT_MIN) {  // INT_MIN and INT_MAX indicates that cell is empty. So if cell is empty loop will break and goto bottom of the loop to insert element
        if (Array3[Position3] == INT_MAX)
            break;
        Position3 = (Position3 + 1) % HashFunction3;
        n++;

        if (n == Size3)
            break;      // If table is full we should break, if not check this, loop will go to infinite loop.
    }

    if (n == Size3)
    {
        cout << "\n##############################################\n";
        cout << " NOTE: Hash table is full of elements or name\n No Place to insert this element or name\n";
        cout << "##############################################\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        Array3[Position3] = ASCIIsum3;    //Inserting element
        cout << "\n===========================================\n";
        cout << " NOTE: " << Element3 << " value number is " << ASCIIsum3 << ".\n Element or name added successfully\n";
        cout << "===========================================\n";
    }
}


void RemoveElementHashTable(int Array4[], int HashFunction4, int Size4)
{
    system("cls");
    int Position4, a, ASCIIsum4 = 0, n = 0;

    string Element4;

    cout << " Enter element or name to remove: ";
    cin >> Element4;

    for (a = 0; a != Element4.length(); ++a)
    {
        ASCIIsum4 += int(Element4[a]);
    }

    Position4 = ASCIIsum4 % HashFunction4;

    while (n++ != Size4) {
        if (Array4[Position4] == INT_MIN) {
            cout << "\n################################################\n";
            cout << " NOTE: Element or name not found in hash table\n";
            cout << "################################################\n\n";
            break;
        }
        else if (Array4[Position4] == ASCIIsum4) {
            Array4[Position4] = INT_MAX;
            cout << "\n===========================================\n";
            cout << " NOTE: " << Element4 << " value number is " << ASCIIsum4 << ".\n Element removed successfully\n";
            cout << "===========================================\n";
            break;
        }
        else {
            Position4 = (Position4 + 1) % HashFunction4;
        }
    }
    if (--n == Size4)
    {
        cout << "\n################################################\n";
        cout << " NOTE: Element or name not found in hash table\n";
        cout << "################################################\n\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    int Size5, HashFunction5, i, UserInput;

    Size5 = 11;
    HashFunction5 = 11;

    int Array5[11];
    system("cls");

    for (i = 0; i < Size5; i++)
        Array5[i] = INT_MIN; //Assigning INT_MIN indicates that cell is empty

    do {
        cout << "-----------------------------\n";
        cout << " Your hash table size is: " << Size5 << "\n";
        cout << "-----------------------------\n";
        cout << " Enter the number below:\n";
        cout << " 1: Add element\n";
        cout << " 2: Remove element\n";
        cout << " 3: Search element\n";
        cout << " 4: Display all element\n"; /* <-- See Line 192 to 197 for detail.*/
        cout << " 0: Exit\n";
        cout << " \n Your selection: ";
        cin >> UserInput;

        switch (UserInput) 
        {
            case 0:
                system("cls");
                cout << " You quit the application\n\n";
                system("pause");
                exit;
                break;
            case 1:
                AddElementHashTable(Array5, HashFunction5, Size5);
                break;
            case 2:
                RemoveElementHashTable(Array5, HashFunction5, Size5);
                break;
            case 3:
                LookUpHashTable(Array5, HashFunction5, Size5);
                break;
            case 4:                                 
                DisplayHashTable(Array5, Size5);    
                break;                              
            default:
                cout << " \nYou entering incorrect choice. Please enter choice above!\n\n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
        }

    } while (UserInput);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's two questions. Do you know how to implement a linked list?

Comment: Unrelated: `exit;` -> `exit(<some number>);` Forgot a few brackets and the exit code.

Comment: @Beta, that what I just said, I don't know how to create or implement a linked list. I know basic but I just don't know how to implement.

Comment: @user4581301, I don't know what do you mean by hard-coded

Comment: Don't worry about it. I get what your problem is and have removed that comment.  A hard coded value is a fixed value. The user enters nothing. It's best to start testing with fixed, known values without the user getting involved because you don't want to have to debug both the user input code and the algorithm under test at the same time.

Comment: Just from curiosity; is this code solely yours, or just the `main()` part? The whole idea of hash table is to encode original input. This is why you get `309` - to hide the content.

Comment: This question is too broad. If you want to learn to implement a linked list, consult your textbook, or any of the *many* online tutorials.

Comment: Similarly you don't want to debug a hash table and a linked list at the same time, so write the linked list separately and test the bejebus out of it before you try to use it with the hash table.

Comment: The best hint for succeessfully implementing a linked list and understanding what you just did so you can do it again later is draw a lot of pictures. Draw the list out on a piece of paper. Draw in all of the links. Draw how you would iterate to find a given link. Draw all of the steps you have to go through to add or remove a link. Draw, draw, draw. And take really good notes because the notes become your code. When you go to debug, first make sure your code  works by going through it one instruction at a time on a piece of paper to make sure you can draw the list. If you can't, that's a bug.

Comment: ok thanks, I will do that.

Comment: @Przemek This code was from the online and this code only input a value not a string so I use this code and change it to string for the user input.